Programmatically how to differentiate between 2 monitors {laptop integrated monitor, and external monitor connected via port}
I wanted to programmatically differentiate between two monitors using some parameters which says:

monitor is 'integrated monitor' of the laptop OR,
monitor is 'external monitor' and connected via port (e.g. HDMI).

DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID specifies the type of display topology, but it does not specify which monitor is connected to which topology (e.g. internal, external clone, external extended, etc.).
I was looking around the PID and VID and other parameters of device manager but could not find relevant information.

c/cpp and win32 api on windows os.

typedef enum DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID { 
 DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_INTERNAL = 0x00000001,
 DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_CLONE = 0x00000002,
 DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_EXTEND = 0x00000004,
 DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_EXTERNAL = 0x00000008,
 DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_FORCE_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF

};
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ne-wingdi-displayconfig_topology_id
